# How to handle orientation change and resource cleaning with mvvm

Tags: android, mvvm, android-lifecycle, android-databinding, kotlin-android-extensions

I try to understund mvvm arhitecture with data binding. Below I write simple example: Loading data from network at fragment starting. Basicaly, it works.

But I have some problems.

**1)** When orientation changed, fragment reloads data from network, because `loadFromNetwork()` calls in `onViewCreated`. ViewModel not recrated, so what correct solution to avoid reloading data? Should I implement "cache" in ViewModel, or make checks in View(Fragment)?

**2)** When Ui destroys, we need dispose network operations. Where to place these cleanings (note: `subscribe` method returns `Disposable`)?

**fragment_my.xml**

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <import type="android.view.View" />
        <import type="com.xxx.State" />
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.xxx.MyViewModel" />
    </data>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@{viewModel.myPojo.data}" />
        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:visibility="@{viewModel.state == State.LOADING ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE}" />
    </FrameLayout>

</layout>
```

**MyViewModel.kt**

```
class MyViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    val state = ObservableField(State.LOADING)

    val myPojo = ObservableField<MyPojo>()

    @Inject
    lateinit var netApi: NetworkApi

    init {
        Injector.getAppComponent().inject(this)
    }

    fun loadFromNetwork() {
        state.set(State.LOADING)

        netApi.getMyPojo().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe({
                    state.set(State.SUCCESS)
                    myPojo.set(it)
                }, {
                    state.set(State.ERROR)
                })
    }

}
```

**MyFragment.kt**

```
class MyFragment : Fragment(){

    private lateinit var mBinding: FragmentMyBinding
    private lateinit var mViewModel: MyViewModel

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        mViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater?, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        mBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_my, container, false)
        return mBinding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        mBinding.viewModel = mViewModel

        mViewModel.loadFromNetwork()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could persist the data to a preference or sqlite database to avoid getting from network each time.  Assuming you don't want to do that, I can think of two choices.  First, the standard approach of storing the data to a bundle in `saveInstanceState` `onDestroy` and reading it back in `onCreate`.  Second, if you have a singleTop "main" activity or fragment, I've had success making the ViewModel static and using that as a way to maintain instance state.